# Groovy sort list asc by name and desc by age

Tags: groovy, soapui

How to sort a list by 2 fields in opposite order? I'm trying to sort a list by name (ascending) and by age (descending). I have tried:

```
list.sort { -it }
```

for descending, and

```
list.sort { it }
```

for ascending order, but it does not take two different fields into account. Is it possible to sort the list like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
def list = [ [name:1, age:2], [name:2, age:10], [name:1, age:20] ]

list = list.sort{ a, b -> a.name <=> b.name ?: b.age <=> a.age }

assert [[name:1, age:20], [name:1, age:2], [name:2, age:10]] == list
```